# Memory leak on [String] constant

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks

I have a really simple Swift Class that has only a single static method, this method allocates 3 arrays of string, and create a random string by appending elements from these arrays.

Here the code:

```
public static func generateText() -> String {

   let phraseComponent1 = [
        "Line 1,",
        "Line2,",
        "Line3,",
        "Line4,",
        "Line5,",
        "Line6,"]

   let phraseComponent2 = [
        "Line 1,",
        "Line2,",
        "Line3,",
        "Line4,",
        "Line5,",
        "Line6,"]

   let phraseComponent3 = [
        "Line 1,",
        "Line2,",
        "Line3,",
        "Line4,",
        "Line5,",
        "Line6,"]

    let componentIndex1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(phraseComponent1.count)))
    let componentIndex2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(phraseComponent2.count)))
    let componentIndex3 = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(phraseComponent3.count)))

    let phrase1 = phraseComponent1[componentIndex1]
    let phrase2 = phraseComponent2[componentIndex2]
    let phrase3 = phraseComponent3[componentIndex3]

    return "\(phrase1) \(phrase2) \(phrase3)"
}
```

It happens that this code is generating a memory leak on the first array as you can see in the screenshot:
[image]

Can someone tell me a reason for it? And how to fix this

Comment: If you call this method billion times discarding return value and draining autorelease pool, will you see heap growth? If not, this is a misleading diagnostic output and you should not worry about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as @werediver mentioned, added a huge loop calling this method, and the heap didn't move, nor the number of leaks, so as he mentioned, this was a misleading diagnostic. No action needed about it.